# How do i add new js code and run on BODY?

Tags: javascript

So, I was adding some new js code to body and i notice that if you add with `$('body').append()`, it works but when i tried to add with `document.body.innerHTML+="some script"`, It doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted with `innerHTML` should not execute.

Have a look at [Element.innerHTML - Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations) and the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).